# Server 2008 Setup Remote Desktop Services

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, terminal-server, remote-desktop-services

I have a 2008 server that I can access via remote desktop as I am the domain admin at my work environment. We are installing some software that will require a handful of users to login and use the software. I've always been confused to what type of licenses I need and the steps to install Remote Desktop Services. Do I just need to buy 5 CALs and install them once I install the required features? It looks like I'll need to install the Remote Desktop Session Host and Remote Desktop Licensing Service? Do I need any license for this part of the install, or does the 5 CALs cover me if I only need 5 concurrent users max?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just need CAL's for the users.

You don't require any other licensing for the install of the features/roles